# Can't write my headers from an excel to another excel in python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlrd, xlsxwriter

I can't get why my code isn't running, I don't know big thing about python but that seems pretty basic, I'm considering the `firstRow` is an array, am I right? Also, I implement my new excel file while `first` is not empty (if i clearly understood how to check if it's empty or not).. Thank you

```
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd

#ouvre l'excel
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myExcel.xlsx', on_demand = True)

#utilise le 2nd spreadsheet
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)

#recupere la premiere ligne (headers) // a priori un array
firstRow = worksheet.row_values(0)


# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook2 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo2.xlsx')
worksheet2 = workbook2.add_worksheet()

number = 0

#pour chaque colonne, l'écrire dans une nouvelle colonne du fichier excel
for first in firstRow:
    while first:
        worksheet2.write(number, 0, first)
        number += 1

workbook2.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine the loop below:

```
for first in firstRow:
    while first:
        worksheet2.write(number, 0, first)
        number += 1
```

We never exit the `while first:` loop because there is always a `first` and it is never changed.  We first open the loop, for `first` in `firstRow`:

> 1) `first` is the value of A1 in your workbook
>
> 2) Now we loop `while first`
>
> 3) We write `first` to the cell at `number`, `0` which is `0, 0`
>
> 4) Increment `number` and repeat `while first` again.
>
> 5) Now write `first` again to the cell at `number`, `0` which now is `1, 0`
>
> 6) Increment `number` and repeat `while first` again.

You can see how we'll never get out of this loop, your program endlessly writes `first` into a new cell.

You may want to use:

```
for first in firstRow:
    worksheet2.write(number, 0, first)
    number += 1
```

Comment: Oh yes what I wrote was pretty stupid, I don't know why I thought I had to stop the loop... Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome, and as an aside, look into `enumerate()` as a way to avoid having to use `number += 1` in your loop.